# Downloading an SQlite .db file

Tags: php, sqlite

Hello currently I am working on a tool that converts an otherwise file-based stored text array(not really important though what it does). It works great and I am able to download and use it if I download the file off the FTP, but when I try to directly download it to the person using the .php file, it says Invalid file. My current code is:

```
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($dbname));
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="object database.db"');
        readfile($dbname);
```

What is the issue? Is the content-type or something else wrong? Or should I be using readfile(I tried this?)

When I download with the above code, the name of the file seems to be correct or whatever but when I attempt to open it with the SQLite3 Browser(it works when I download directly off the FTP) the program displays "Invalid file format". When I use readfile it downloads as "download" with no file extension and when I attempt to open windows says Invalid file. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `application/db` content type. You should use `application/octet-stream` instead. Also `filename` in `Content-Disposition` is just filename you suggest client to save file as, but nothing more, so you yet needs to send the file content itself to the remote peer.

```
readfile(....);
die();
```

should do the work if your data is stored in the file already, otherwise you can just `echo()` it instead.

Comment: The code(check the main post, I've updated it) still seems to give invalid file format. Any further help? It should also be noted that the $dbname variable stores the path to the file. An odd think is in chrome the download path seems to be the path of the index.php file when the file  I'm trying to download is in ./tempdbs which is actually in the directory, but a seperate folder itself.